# regular expression to capture pdf data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this code to get specific data from a pdf that is already converted to a string.
basically, this is the string i have after that.

```
Valor del Fondo (Mill COP)
1,308,906.95
Valor fondo de
inversión  (Mill COP)
                           230,942.51 Inversión inicial mínima (COP)\
```

I need a regular expression that captures de numbers only, I expect something like this:
[1308906.95, 230942.51]

this is my NodeJS code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdfparse = require('pdf-parse');

const pdffile = fs.readFileSync('testdoc3.pdf');

pdfparse(pdffile).then(function (data) {
   var myre = /(V|v)alor\s(del)?(\s)?(fondo)(\s)?(de)?(\s)?(inversi(ó|o)n)?/gim
   var array = myre.exec(data.text);
   console.log(array[0]);
});
```

this is the code I have so far, I would really appreciate your help since I have tried a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Try `console.log(Array.from(data.text.matchAll(/valor(?:\s+del)?\s+fondo(?:\s+de\s+inversi[óo]n)?\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)/gi), x=>x[1]).map(x => x.replace(/,/g, '')))`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2eAPp/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = 'Valor del Fondo (Mill COP)\n1,308,906.95\nValor fondo de\ninversión  (Mill COP)\n\n                          230,942.51 Inversión inicial mínima (COP)\\';
console.log(
  Array.from(text.matchAll(
    /valor(?:\s+del)?\s+fondo(?:\s+de\s+inversi[óo]n)?\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)/gi),
    x=>x[1])
  .map(x => x.replace(/,/g, ''))
);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2eAPp/1). *Regex details*:

- `valor` - a `valor` string
- `(?:\s+del)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces and then `del`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `fondo` - a fixed string
- `(?:\s+de\s+inversi[óo]n)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces, `de`, one or more whitespaces, `inversion`
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)` - Group 1: a digit and then an optional sequence of zero or more digits, commas or dots and then a digit.

`String#matchAll` finds all non-overlapping occurrences, `Array.from(..., x=>x[1])` gets Group 1 values and `.map(x => x.replace(/,/g, '')` removes commas from the values obtained.